# Rendering a Razor view to a string, not working when called from another controller. Losing Context?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am new to MVC applications and I am trying to render a razor view to a string. The code I have works great when it is called from within its own controller, though when I try to call the controller from another controller, even though I am sending it the ControllerContext the Controller context end up being null. I am sure I am losing the Context somewhere I just cannot figure out where.

Here is some code.

This is where I call the controller.

```
var emailController = new EmailController();
emailController.ControllerContext = this.ControllerContext;
emailController.SendMail(entry.email, entry.first, entry.word);
```

This is where I call the method that will return a string of html. Where "Template" is a view(Template.cshtml) and emailTemplate is a model that I just create.

```
var emailTemplate = new EmailModel 
{ 
    name = name,
    emailAddress = emailAddress,
    sent = "not Sent"
};    

htmlFromView = renderRazorViewToString("Template", emailTemplate);
```

This is my method that should return a string of html from the view. The issue is that viewContext is returning null.

```
private string renderRazorViewToString(string viewname, object model)
    {
        ViewData.Model = model;
        using (var sW = new StringWriter())
        {
            var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, viewname);
            var viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View, ViewData, TempData, sW);
            viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sW);
            viewResult.ViewEngine.ReleaseView(ControllerContext, viewResult.View);
            return sW.GetStringBuilder().ToString();

        }
    }
```

This works perfectly if I do not call the EmailController from my other controller. Do I need to pass the context to the model as well or something like that?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized my issue was that since I was calling the action result from another controller it was looking for the view in the stock search locations in that controller that was calling the other action result.

Solution: move view into stock search location for that controller calling the other action result.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for partials. I assume it would work for non-partials as well by just using the view name.

```
protected string RenderPartialViewToString(string viewName, object model)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName))
       viewName = ControllerContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");
    ViewData.Model = model;
    using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, viewName);
        ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View, ViewData, TempData, sw);
        viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
         return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
    }
 }
```

Comment: Note: This code needs to be placed in a base controller class that your email controller derives from because of the routing.